# div moves to the left when slideUp() is called

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have a page that has a form with two parts,a one that's shown and a one that's hidden when the user presses the button in the first div, it slide up using slideUp() and the hidden div slides down using slideDown(), the problem is when the first div slides up it moves to the left for a second until the hidden div slides down then it returns to it's normal position, i know it's because of another div i have next to the form, because it works fine if i remove it, i have o idea what's causing this please help.

the divs

```
<div class="tips">

 //irrelevant                   

 </div> 

 <form action="rideHandler.php" method="POST" id="tripinfo">
   <div class ="choosing" id="choosing" >
    
     <button type="button" class="subBtn" id="show"> Finish up</button>
   </div>
   

  <div class="confirmation" id="confirmation" style ="display:none";>

  </div>

</form>
```

the javascript

```
$('#show').click(function(e) {
     
 $("#choosing").slideUp();
 $("#confirmation").slideDown();
```

the CSS

```
.tips{
    background-color: white;
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;
    width:20vw;
    height:35vw;
    padding:80px;
    margin-right:50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-width: 3px 4px 3px 5px;
    border-radius:95% 4% 92% 5%/4% 95% 6% 95%;
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    margin-top:90px;
    
}

.choosing, .confirmation{
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      padding:20px;
      width:35vw;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      border: 3px solid;
      margin-top:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something about the way that jQuery has implemented `slideUp()` seems to be disagreeing with your `auto` side `margin`s.  I fixed it in the example below by using a `calc` to set the side `margin`s instead, but you could probably accomplish a similar result using `flex`.

```js
$('#show').click(function(e) {

  $("#choosing").slideUp();
  $("#confirmation").slideDown();
})
```

```css
.tips {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 35vw;
  padding: 80px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-width: 3px 4px 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 95% 4% 92% 5%/4% 95% 6% 95%;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.choosing,
.confirmation {
  margin: 0 calc(50% - 17.5vw); /* changed this line */
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 35vw;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tips">

  //irrelevant

</div>

<form action="rideHandler.php" method="POST" id="tripinfo">
  <div class="choosing" id="choosing">

    <button type="button" class="subBtn" id="show"> Finish up</button>
  </div>


  <div class="confirmation" id="confirmation" style="display:none" ;>

  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `float` and `inline` property.
And use margin correctly to align the `.tips` block.

```js
$('#show').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#choosing").slideUp();
  $("#confirmation").slideDown();
});
```

```css
.tips {
  background-color: white;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 35vw;
  padding: 80px;
  margin: 0 50px 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-width: 3px 4px 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 95% 4% 92% 5%/4% 95% 6% 95%;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.choosing,
.confirmation {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 35vw;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tips">

  //irrelevant

</div>

<form action="rideHandler.php" method="POST" id="tripinfo">
  <div class="choosing" id="choosing">

    <button type="button" class="subBtn" id="show"> Finish up</button>
  </div>


  <div class="confirmation" id="confirmation" style="display:none" ;>

  </div>

</form>
```